# Output difference using 'grep - i *.sh' and 'grep -i .sh'. Please explain this anomaly?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

`grep - i *.sh` and `grep -i .sh` giving different Outputs. But both should have same output.

```
cat baklol.sh | grep - i *.sh
```

A file `baklol.sh` contains this:

```
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/bulldozer_nightly_config.sh --output-document=bulldozer_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/51_nightly_config.sh --output-document=51_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/60_nightly_config.sh --output-document=60_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/crane_nightly_config.sh --output-document=crane_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/70_nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/trunk_nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
```

command 1: cat baklol.sh | grep - i .sh

```
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/bulldozer_nightly_config.sh --output-document=bulldozer_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/51_nightly_config.sh --output-document=51_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/60_nightly_config.sh --output-document=60_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/crane_nightly_config.sh --output-document=crane_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/70_nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/trunk_nightly_config.sh --output-document=nightly_config.sh
```

command 2: cat baklol.sh | grep - i *.sh

```
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/51_nightly_config.sh --output-document=51_nightly_config.sh
#wget  ${WGET_OPTS} "$BASE_URL"/kits/client_setup/60_nightly_config.sh --output-document=60_nightly_config.sh
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `.sh`? Please read some basic tutorial about shell...

Comment: [What are you actually trying to find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and are you trying to find it in a file or in the output of a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no space between - and i
It should be 
grep -i .sh

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect them to have the same output? Whitespace is *not* arbitrary in Bash.

`grep -i .sh` does a **case insensitive** (`-i`) search for any character (`.`) followed by `sh` in **standard input**.

`grep - i *.sh` will simply search for the string `-` in the **file named exactly `i` and all files ending with `.sh`** in the current directory:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ printf - > i
$ grep - i *.sh
i:-
grep: *.sh: No such file or directory
```

Command 2 is almost nonsensical - if there is a single shell file in the current directory, `*.sh` will expand to that file name (presumably `baklol.sh`), and *that* will be the **pattern** for `grep`. In other words, you're searching inside `baklol.sh` for a string starting with `baklol`, followed by any single character (`.`), followed by `sh`. If you have multiple `.sh` files in the directory, the `man` page seems to indicate that it will search the second and following files for the pattern corresponding to the first file name, and *ignore* standard input.

Comment: What will be the Output then and why? please explain?

Comment: What do you mean? The output when? Please try it, and let us know exactly what you tried, the results you got and how that differed from your expectations.

Comment: I have added the commands and respective output. Please explain the second output using grep -i *.sh command.